# Converting Fortran 77 code to Python

Tags: python, fortran, fortran77

I have looked at this Q/A [Intent of this Fotran77 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719258/what-is-the-intent-of-this-fortran-77-code) and I have almost converted the below Fortran77 style code into Python 3.x except I had a doubt where the i = i + 1 should be placed in the Python version. As mentioned in the comments of the linked question I have done the conformance tests and the results are off by a margin of 2. Hence the question.

```
i = 0
500 continue
i = i +1
if (i .le. ni) then
  if (u(i,j-1) .gt. -9999.) then
     r(1,j) = u(i,j-1)
     go to 600
  else
    missing = i
    go to 500
  end if
 end if
600  continue
```

Here is my Python version

```
  i = 0
  while (i <= ni):
     i = i+1
     if (u[i,j-1] > -9999.0):
         r[0,j] = u[i,j-1]
         break
     else:
       missing = i
```

Did I place the increment counter at the right location ?

Comment: Fortran starts at 1 for lists, it's 0 for python

Comment: if you want it equivalent, probably. the best is to debug/print the values on both program. It's just a question of finetuning now. but my memory is fuzzy. Is there a loop in your fortran program?

Comment: yes, but the off-by-one index issue is probably there for j as well. And my question was "is there a loop in the code you're showing?" because AFAIR a loop is `DO I in 1,5` ... the python version has a loop, the fortran code doesn't seem to have a loop.

Comment: there is no loop in the Fortran code.  statement 500 is not referenced.  what do you mean by 'implicit' ?

Comment: @ShpielMeister - you are absolutely right ! I made an edit.

Comment: The first if in the Fortran isn't completed.  How about getting the Fortran working first with do loop ?

Comment: @tim18 Added the closing end if :)

Comment: are you intending to use the same 1- base indexing as the fortran? (if you go that way you will not be able to use any python list operations). Your code is wrong either way..

Comment: @agentp - I am using numpy arrays.

Comment: that doesnt answer the question. your loop starts at `u[1, ]`. You can work that way if you like. dont use the first element and make the array one bigger than needed.

Comment: what is done with `missing` in the following code?

Comment: @agentp - thanks for your help and persistence :) I am truly grateful. missing is part of a long loop/subroutine . It is all fortran 77 and not written by me but I have the job of making it more modern :) I can show the full code but only if you insist.

Comment: `missing` should be initialized. (Sloppy old fortan assumption to assume it is initially zero).  More importantly is the numeric value actually used or is it just go-no-go flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly translating is not advised because you loose a number of nice efficient coding features of python.

To do this properly in python you should 1) recognize the 0- index convention of python, and 2 )  recognize that that fortran is column major and python is row major so you should reverse the index ordering for all multi-dimensional arrays.

If you do that the loop can be written:

```
try: 
 r[j,0]=[val for val in u[j] if val > -9999 ][0]
 missing=False
except:
 missing=True
```

I'm assuming we don't actually need the numeric value of missing.
If you need it you will have something like this:

```
try: 
 missing,r[j,0]=[(index,val) for (index,val) in enumerate(u[j]) if val > -9999 ][0]
except:
 missing=-1
```

You could also use `next` which would be faster, but it gets a little trickier handling the missing condition.

Comment: thats right. with a single index eg `u[j]` refers to the entire `j`th row.